# Chrome and Firefox have different vertical alignment for text

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve that the text inside a div has the same padding-top in Firefox and in Chrome? In Firefox it has apadding-top of in this case 3px by default and Chrome only has 2px.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJB4F/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{
border: 1px solid;
background: lightblue;
height: 50px;
width: 120px;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to vertical align text inside the div.

Refer the question to get your answer [Vertically align text in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepbindash/z7Fgu/)

You have `50px` height in your div. So just simple give `line-height:50px;` property to your class. If you increase your height of your `div` , then increase you line-height as well.

If you want the align the text to center, then add the `text-align:center;`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set the text's leading with the CSS `line-height` property. Different browsers will likely have different defaults.

http://jsfiddle.net/vJB4F/2/

Comment: Compare FF and Chrome, your solution does not work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJB4F/5/)

Comment: Please take a closer look at my code, that's not what I did. I used a pixel value so the height of line block will always be the same across browsers. There will _always_ be subtle differences in the rendering of glyphs between browsers, either because of rendering technology or font variation or format used.

Comment: [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJB4F/8/) -> even with pixels, there is a difference of 1 Pixel, which looks strange, if working with a small font inside a small box. Seems there is no solution.

Answer (score -2):

Do you use a reset css ?
See http://www.cssreset.com/, and test with.

Comment: I did, but counting the pixels to the top, chrome still is different [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJB4F/6/)

Answer (score -2):

The different browsers and their cores are using different default settings in the html code.
THe simplest solution is to use every time a reset css code.
That code must be included just before your code and will rearrange all the differences you may find further.

[A reset css example](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: A reset CSS doesn't 'rearrange' differences (like [normalise CSS](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)), it _removes_ default styles.

Comment: You got the idea.. My English is not perfect!